# Typescript AMD and AngularJs - Failed to instantiate module

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, requirejs, typescript, amd

I'm unsing TypeScript AMD (RequireJs) and AngularJs.

I want to use AMD for my typescript code and not for the rest: jquery, angular, bootstrap, ...
For thirdparty js I'm using MVC bundling and I want to continue this way.

This is my thirdparty bundle config:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/thirdparty").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
            "~/Scripts/respond.js",
            "~/Scripts/require.js",
            "~/Scripts/angular.js",
            "~/Scripts/angular-route.js"
            ));
```

My _Layout.cshtml is something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="PafBase">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/thirdparty")

    <script>
        require.config({
            baseUrl: 'typescript/'
        });
        require(['module/BaseApplication']);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  @RenderBody()
</body>
```

BaseApplication.ts is something like:

```
var app: ng.IModule = angular.module('PafBase', ['ngRoute']); // Breakpoint here ****
app.config(['$routeProvider', ($routeProvider) => { ... }]);
```

When run the application I get this javascript error:

```
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module PafBase due to:

Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'PafBase' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

If I continue the execution I can see that BaseApplication.ts is executed after the angular error.

I think it can be due to angular scan the DOM after ready and found `<html ng-app="PafBase">` then search "PafBase" module and not find it due to requireJs don't load `BaseApplication.ts` before angular scan the DOM.

How to do angular scan the dom after my code is executed?

Comment: As rob said. Base application isn't loaded when ng app is detected by angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually bootstrap Angular instead of specifying `ng-app="PafBase"`. Take a look at the docs here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

Basically you just need to remove `ng-app` from your html and add this to your JS

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['PafBase']);
});
```